# How do I restart my Perl script on Windows 10

Tags: perl, windows-10, restart

I have a Perl script with a GUI that restarts itself, if I press a button in the GUI.
This is done through this simple call in the callback of the button:
`exec( $pathToMyself );`
This works fine on Windows 7. But on Windows 10, the script ends (and the GUI disappears), but it doesn't restart, unless I go to the command window, which I used to initially call the script, and press the `Enter` key there.
I don't like this behavior. Can anyone explain, where this comes from or give me a hint on how to restart my script without having to press `Enter`?
Thanks, Gerhard

Here's a simple reproducible example:

```
    use Tk;
    use strict;
    my $pathToMyself = $0;

    my $mw = MainWindow->new();
    my $but = $mw->Button(-text => "Restart", -command => \&restartMe)->pack();
    MainLoop;

    sub restartMe {
      print "Restarting $pathToMyself...\n";
      exec( $pathToMyself );
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added an example to my original post (as it's not possible to get decent code formatting done in a comment)